# Trying to get property of non-object PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array, object

Tengo el siguiente problema:

La idea del script es obtener un listado de los nombres de los proveedores de una tabla. La tabla tiene varias columnas que va desde el id, hasta el último que es la fecha en el que el proveedor fue creado en el sistema, pasando por el nombre, y demás datos de interés.

El script es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    include_once "php/conexion.php";
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM proveedores;");
    $proveedor = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>
<?php
    foreach ($proveedor as $nombre) {
        echo $nombre->nombre;
        }
    print_r($nombre);
?>
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\system\test\operar_proveedorx.php
>   on line 8

line 8 correspondería a `echo $nombre->nombre;`

Estuve indagando un poco, y al final puse el `print_r` para ver qué imprime la variable, e imprime una fecha que se corresponde con la fecha de creación del proveedor en el sistema, y que se ubica en la última columna de la tabla y solo imprime el dato correspondiente al primer proveedor, es decir, con el id 1.

La idea final, sería poder hacer un `echo` de todos los nombres de proveedores en links o buttons, para acceder a otro script que permita el acceso a la edición de los datos de cada uno según corresponda.

Por otro lado, he probado el script de la siguiente manera para buscar opciones:

```
<?php
    include_once "php/conexion.php";
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM proveedores;");
    $proveedor = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
?>
<?php
    echo $proveedor->nombre;
?>
```

Los cambios básicamente fueron:

- `mysqli_fetch_array` a `mysqli_fetch_object`
- de la variable $nombre a $proveedor en el `echo`
- eliminado el foreach

El resultado es sencillamente el nombre del primer proveedor.

Espero poder resolverlo.
Muchas gracias a todos y saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente con **mysqli_fetch_array** devuelves todos los registros como arreglo por consiguiente si quieres mostrar el nombre de cada uno de ellos debes:

```
<?php
    include_once "php/conexion.php";
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM proveedores;");

    while($proveedor = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       echo $proveedor['nombre'].', ';
    }
?>
```

Y si lo haces con **mysqli_fetch_object** deberia quedarte como habias elaborado al comienzo:

```
<?php
    include_once "php/conexion.php";
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM proveedores;");

    while($proveedor = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
       echo $proveedor->nombre.', ';
    }
?>
```

La diferencia esta en como te devuelve cada registro en el caso 1 es un arreglo por tanto cuando desees mostraru obtener alguna de las columnas es con $elemento['nombre_columna'] y en el segundo caso devuelve un SplObject por tanto puedes acceder al valor de la columna de cada fila dentro del foreach con $elemento->nombre_columna. Espero haberte podido ayudar ;P

**EDIT**, según la documentación de php https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-array.php las funciones mysqli_fetch_** devuelven una fila del resultado de tu consulta, por consiguiente si quieres obtenerlos todos tienes que seguir llamandola, y ella se encargara de mover el cursor hacia la proxima fila de tus resultados de la consulta ejecutada previamente, por consiguiente se puede ver casi siempre metida dentro de un ciclo while, tal y como te lo mostré, aunque es posible tambien verlo dentro de un for no obstante para comenzar aqui tienes ya unos avances

**EDIT2**:

Si quieres seguir usando foreach como me comentastes, puedes hacer uso de mysqli_fetch_all de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    include_once "php/conexion.php";
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM proveedores;");

    foreach(mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $proveedor){
       echo $proveedor['nombre'].', ';
    }
?>
```

Con esa nueva función retornas todos los registros en un arreglo y no necesitas del while, y por tanto puedes usar el foreach

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder.
Con `mysqli_fecth_array` y el `echo($nombre['nombre'];` , me da como resultado:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'nombre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\system\test\operar_proveedorx.php on line 8

Y con `mysqli_fetch_object`, da el resultado original, Trying to get property on non-object.

Sigo intentando.

Comment: en vez de hacer con la primera opción echo $nombre['nombre'] dentro del foreach haz un print_r($nombre); break; y dime que te muestra, con la segunda opción puedes hacer algo parecido pero en vez de print_r pon var_dump($nombre)

Comment: Bien, con la primera opción, usando `mysqli_fetch_array` y `print_r($nombre)` muestra los datos de la primera fila todos juntos, uno al lado del otro. Con la segunda opción, usando `mysqli_fecth_object` y `var_dump($nombre)`, aparece la palabra `string`y entre paréntesis, la cantidad de caracteres que hay en la celda del dato, por ejemplo (1) para el primer dato que es el `id`, (4) para el que sigue que es el nombre, y así para todos los datos, siempre del primer proveedor.
Gracias!

Comment: Edite la respuesta ya espero que asi si te funcione ;P

Comment: Gracias!, con `while` funciona. En realidad, la idea era usar `foreach`, porque el script original estaba usando ese loop. Quería ver si podía usarlo.

Comment: Volvi a editar la respuesta, si funciona la respuesta marcala como aceptada para que los que vengan detras de ti puedan saber por cual guiarse. ;P

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, no se qué diferencia sustancial hay en usar `while` o `foreach`, si el resultado es el mismo. Mi script original estaba usando `foreach` pero en PDO, y tenía que cambiar todo a MysQLi. La idea es que de esa lista de proveedores, pueda acceder a otra página con sus datos para editarlos o eliminarlos. Gracias a tu última edición de las respuesta, voy a usar `foreach`, y además probaré con `while` para ver si surgen diferencias. Muchísimas gracias!